# wkhtmltopdf with docker : some css are not used

Tags: php, docker, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use wkhtmltopdf with docker on a symfony project :

```
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf
FROM openjdk:19-jdk-alpine3.16 

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libstdc++ \
    libx11 \
    libxrender \
    libxext \
    libssl1.1 \
    ca-certificates \
    fontconfig \
    freetype \
    ttf-dejavu \
    ttf-droid \
    ttf-freefont \
    ttf-liberation \
    # more fonts
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    msttcorefonts-installer \
  # Install microsoft fonts
  && update-ms-fonts \
  && fc-cache -f \
  # Clean up when done
  && rm -rf /tmp/* \
  && apk del .build-deps

# Copy wkhtmltopdf files from docker-wkhtmltopdf image
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox* /usr/local/bin/
```

But the pdf generated is not exactly the same as the html one, as some css are not taken into account. If I switch to a standard local installation (based on Debian 11), pdf are generated correctly.

So, my questions are :

- what is missing with my docker install ?
- how to debug wkhtmltopdf in order to find out where is the problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem of ignored CSS with wkhtmltopdf.

I know my answer will not exactly fit to what you are looking for but i think it is good to know https://www.api2pdf.com/ to prevent developper to try to make pdf themselves

I've been strugling with wkhtmltopdf (binaries and shit...) everywhere i had to install it for years.
One day a friend told me about api2pdf. It is very cheap and easy to use. I never used my own generator ever again.

Especiallacy because of their `chromeHtmlToPdf` function which is the function you are looking for to fix your css problem.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your answer but I can't use external API on the project I'm working right now, so I really need to make wkhtmltopdf work with docker

Comment: Sorry to hear that; i hope you will find a way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old , but encountered same recently. in my case i was on docker , ubuntu .
using xvfb might work :

apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf

then run the wkhtmltopdf  with xvfb e.g

`xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/ github.pdf`